# Display Javascript variable into PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript, forms, variables

In my form action there's a url: **www.url.com/?quantity=$quantity**

And in the form there's a select box where customers choose the quantity.

```
<form method="post" name="jform" action="www.url.com/?quantity=$quantity">
<select class="font_12" id="quantity" name="quantity">
    <option value="10">10 PCs</option>
    <option value="25">25 PCs</option>
    <option value="50">50 PCs</option>
    <option value="99">99 PCs</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to get the value in the select box using ajax, and then display into the action form url. I did a alert and it works, I am getting the value of the select box.
But I don't know how to put this vaue into the PHP varaible **$quantity**?

Here's my Ajax code:

```
$('#quantity').on('change', function() {
var val = $(this).val();
if(val != '') {
    $.get('index.php', {'quantity' : val}, function(resp) {
        alert(val);
    });
}
});
```

Actually I want it to change the php variable right away when the quantity in the select box change before submitting the form.

Any help?

Comment: *When* do you want PHP to be able to access the `quantity` variable?

Comment: I try $_GET, but when the page load I am getting a undefined error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$_GET`

If your URL is `?quantity=###` then just use `$_GET['quantity']` in your PHP code.

To change the action attribute on the form when you change the quantity you can just put the following inside your onchange event:

```
$('form[name="jform"]').attr('action','http://url.com/?quantity=' + val);
```

Comment: and be careful to properly control your users' input

Comment: not working, the url is in the form action. I want it to change the quantity of the form action url when a value in the select value is changed.

Comment: Well then since you're using jQuery you can just say `$('form[name="jform"]').attr('action','http://url.com/?quantity=' + val);`

Comment: Oh thank you so much, but how about if I am using a php function in the action like:`<form method="post" name="jform" action="<?php echo url($quantity) ?>">`

Comment: Then you can use `action="http://url.com/?quantity=<?php echo (int)$_GET['quantity']; ?>"`

Comment: Nevermind, it's not working. Because the `action="<?php echo getPurchaseLink($link = 4, $csvfile, $quantity = +val); ?>"` is like that. So I don't know how to split out the quantity varaible and put the js variable in it.

Comment: Well the quantity variable is `$_GET['quantity']` but in your javascript it's `val`. So if you wanted to change it and update the purchase link you'd probably have to either make a JS function similar to your getPurchaseLink function or make an AJAX call to some file that returns `getPurchaseLink(4, $csvfile, (int)$_GET['quantity']);` Or you could play around with the current URL and just tack on `&quantity=val` to the end of it.

Comment: Thx I think I will try some Ajax with it.

Comment: I found the solution, I use get $_REQUEST which get the post from ajax and it;s work same as $_GET. Thanks